# MySQL function retuns undefined, but does connect

Tags: node.js

I have a bit of a weird problem, I have a function called `MySQL.Connect()` which returns `true` if it connected succesfully, and `false` if it didn't connect. The problem is, it did connect, because the SELECT-query gives me back results from the database, but the function returns `undefined` (so neither `true` or `false`. The class the function is in is the following:

**RP_MySQL.js:**

```js
module.exports = class RP_MySQL {
    constructor(host, user, password, database) {
        this.host = host;
        this.user = user;
        this.password = password;
        this.database = database;
        this.mysql = require('mysql');
        this.connection = null;
        this.connected = false;
    }

    Connect() {
        this.connection = this.mysql.createConnection({
            host: this.host,
            user: this.user,
            password: this.password,
            database: this.database
        });

        this.connection.connect(function(thrownError) {
            console.log(thrownError);
            if(thrownError) {
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And the following is where I call the function:

**Execute.js:**

```js
var RP_MySQL = require('./Classes/RP_MySQL');
var RP_Log = require('./Classes/RP_Log');

var MySQL = new RP_MySQL("localhost", "root", "", "somedatabase");
var Log = new RP_Log();

if(MySQL.Connect()) {
    Log.Info("Successfully connected to database");
} else {
    Log.Critical("Error connecting to database");
}

MySQL.connection.query("SELECT * FROM vehicles", function(err, results, fields){
    console.log(results);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your are returning `true/false` within the callback of `.connect`.

You can provide a callback to your `Connect` method which will give you the connection status.

```
Connect(callback) {
    // <Snip>
    this.connection.connect(function(thrownError) {
        console.log(thrownError);
        if(thrownError == null) {
            return callback(true);
        } else {
            return callback(false);
        }
    });
 }

 // Elsewhere
 MYSQL.Connect(status => {
    if (status) {
        Log.Info("Successfully connected to database");
    } else {
        Log.Critical("Error connecting to database");
    }
}
```

In node-world the general pattern is that a callback takes the form `function(error, result)` and you check if `error` has a value before proceeding.

[Here](https://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/getting-started/control-flow/what-are-callbacks/) is an article about callbacks.

Comment: That did the trick! Thanks! Apparently going from a conventional programming language to Node.JS still has some stuff I need to know. Thanks!